# Customizing Ubuntu's splash screen and welcome text

Tags: custom-distributions

I've created my own customized version of Ubuntu 12.04 using [ubuntu-builder](http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/), but now I would like to get rid of the default splash screen and the welcome text related to Ubuntu that appear during the boot process and change it to my own customized welcome screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not. Look in the directory `/usr/share/images/` there would be directory containing images of different resolution. Replace those images with your custom images. Make sure to place your image in all resolution given there, and you are done.  You can even customize logo and welcome message with your quotes or any thing you like.

File `/etc/motd` contains welcome message.

Comment: "You can even customize logo and welcome message with your quotes or any thing you like" How would I do that?

Comment: try modifying `/etc/motd`

Comment: there is also [graphical way](http://www.howtogeek.com/112974/how-to-customize-ubuntu-with-ubuntu-tweak/). I do prefer doing it by hand then using this GUI based thing.